# Reset variable value when leaving method

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a non-performance critical method, where I need to set the value of some class member variable for the lifetime of the method. For example:

```
class myClass
{
    public:
        void myFunc()
        {
            mLocked = true;
            // Do something...
            mLocked = false;
        }

    private:
        bool mLocked;
};
```

I want the variable to be reset to the previous value when myFunc returns. Setting mLocked to true and false seems unreliable, just incase someone adds a return in the middle of the method.

I've solved this by creating an RAII template class that sets the value in the constructor, and cleans up in the destructor...

```
    template<typename T>
class ScopedSetValue
{
    public:
        ScopedSetValue(
            T *pointer,
            T constructorValue,
            T destructorValue)
        {
            mPointer = pointer;
            mDestructorValue = destructorValue;
            if(nullptr != mPointer)
                *mPointer = constructorValue;
        }

        ScopedSetValue(
            T *pointer,
            T destructorValue)
        {
            mPointer = pointer;
            mDestructorValue = destructorValue;
        }

        ~ScopedSetValue()
        {
            if(nullptr != mPointer)
                *mPointer = mDestructorValue;
        }

    private:
        T *mPointer;
        T mDestructorValue;
};
```

Then myFunc just does:

```
void myFunc()
{
    ScopedSetValue<bool> scoped(&mLocked, true, false);
    return; // Set mLocked back to false
}
```

This all works fine... but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. I'm curious if anyone knows if something like this already exists in the standard library? I can't find anything, but I kind of feel that it's generic enough that I shouldn't be writing this myself.

It's a small enough chunk of code that if I am reinventing the wheel, it's not terrible, but I'm just trying to reduce the amount of duplicated code in an ever expanding codebase, if there's already something nice that will do this.

Comment: Side note: You can get rid of the null checks if you accept a reference instead.

Comment: What is wrong with [`std::unique_ptr`](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)  and [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)  ?

Comment: This seems a rather particular niche - a non-atomic, non-synchronized variable that must have a certain value while a particular function is running. Who then observes the changed value? And given the peculiarity, it's fairly obvious why there would not be Standard Library support

Comment: Relying on such state reeks of bad practice. If the code needs the lock value, it should be injected into it, not just kept in the state where it can be changed.

Comment: You're not reinventing the wheel. You're reinventing the stick. It's trivial enough that you probably won't find it in any library, and is probably not worth getting any library for.

Answer (score 1):

There's no completely general scope guard. You can use a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) with a custom deleter. You'd have to decide for yourself if that looks too ugly; maybe with some [`using` declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) you can make it nicer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    bool flag = false;
    std::cout << flag << '\n';
    {
        std::unique_ptr<bool, std::function<void(bool*)>> resetter(
                &(flag=true),
                [](bool* flag){ *flag = false; });
        std::cout << flag << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << flag << '\n';
}
```

prints:

```
0
1
0
```

---

But as mentioned above, this seems a little odd... do you expect someone else to be observing this class member throughout (in which case, you need real synchronisation)? Otherwise you might be better to have this variable be local, or passed as an argument into functions you call.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
template <typename F>
class Finally {
    F f;
public:
    template <typename Func>
    Finally(Func&& func) : f(std::forward<Func>(func)) {}
    ~Finally() { /* try */ f();  /* catch(...) {} */ }

    Finally(const Finally&) = delete;
    Finally(Finally&&) = delete;
    Finally& operator =(const Finally&) = delete;
    Finally& operator =(Finally&&) = delete;
};

template <typename F>
Finally<F> make_finally(F&& f)
{
    return { std::forward<F>(f) };
}
```

And then

```
mLocked = true;
auto finally = make_finally([this](){ mLocked = false; });
// Do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
template <typename T>
class RevertValueOnScopeExit
{
public:
    T& value;
    T original;
    RevertValueOnScopeExit(T& source)
        :value(source),original(source)
    {
    }

    ~RevertValueOnScopeExit()
    {
        value = original;
    }
};
```

Your code would look like this:

```
RevertValueOnScopeExit<bool> revert(mLocked);
mLocked = true;
```